# How to get 3D Pie Chart using MVC4 Chart Helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, charts

after seeing this link http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart and watch the Pie Chart, I want to be able to create the same chart in my MVC4 page.

When I use Pie chart, the 2D pie chart is drawn. How can I get that 3D chart?

This is the code of the view:

```
@{
var grafico = new Chart(width: 200, height: 200, theme: ChartTheme.Vanilla)
        .AddTitle("Cantidad de Servicios por Día")
        .AddSeries(
            chartType: "Pie",
            name: "CantidadServiciosPorDia",
            xValue: @ViewData["X"] as string[],
            yValues: @ViewData["Y"] as string[])
        .Write();
}
```

Cheers,
Jaime

Comment: I've not used this control, but my guess is that you can use radial gradient fills to achieve the '3D' effect in the diagram in the tutorial.

Comment: where I can use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Vanilla3D theme:

```
@{
  var grafico = new Chart(width: 200, height: 200, theme: ChartTheme.Vanilla3D)
                .AddTitle("Cantidad de Servicios por Día")
                .AddSeries(
                chartType: "Pie",
                name: "CantidadServiciosPorDia",
                xValue: @ViewData["X"] as string[],
                yValues: @ViewData["Y"] as string[])
                .Write();
```

}

Good luck.